# Function to download data from the EIA's API via R stopped working why?

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out why my function to download data from the EIA stopped working. Why did the following code stop working?

```
getWDEIA <- function(ID, key) {

ID <- unlist(strsplit(ID, ";"))
key <- unlist(strsplit(key, ";"))

url <- paste("http://api.eia.gov/series?series_id=", ID, "&api_key=", key, 
    "&out=xml", sep = "")

doc <- xmlParse(file = url, isURL = TRUE)

df <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//data/row"))

df <- arrange(df, df$date)

date <- as.Date(df$date, "%Y%m%d")
values <- as.numeric(levels(df[, -1]))[df[, -1]]

xts_data <- xts(values, order.by = date)
names(xts_data) <- sapply(strsplit(ID, "-"), paste, collapse = ".")

assign(sapply(strsplit(ID, "-"), paste, collapse = "."), xts_data, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

    getWDEIA(ID = "PET.W_EPC0_FPF_R48_MBBLD.4", key = key)
```

Comment: The error message is "Error in order(df$date) : argument 1 is not a vector". Also, the API keys are free. I have created a dummy api key for testing. "E7FDCCBA39FBA0268555B7E81D73CD47"

Answer (score 1):

It seems you did not look at the raw XML from the API before posting the question here. there is no `//data/row` XPath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eia_api>
  <request>
    <command>series</command>
    <series_id>PET.W_EPC0_FPF_R48_MBBLD.4</series_id>
  </request>
  <series>
    <row>
      <series_id>PET.W_EPC0_FPF_R48_MBBLD.4</series_id>
      <name>Lower 48 States Field Production of Crude Oil, 4 Week Avg</name>
      <units>Thousand Barrels per Day</units>
      <f>4</f>
      <unitsshort>Mbbl/d</unitsshort>
      <description>Lower 48 States Field Production of Crude Oil</description>
      <copyright>None</copyright>
      <source>EIA, U.S. Energy Information Administration</source>
      <start/>
      <end/>
      <updated>2015-08-05T13:14:06-0400</updated>
      <data/>
    </row>
  </series>
</eia_api>
```

You also didn't include 2 necessary `library` calls. The modified function below just returns the data frame from the correctly targeted path:

```
library(XML)
library(dplyr)

getWDEIA <- function(ID, key) {

  ID <- unlist(strsplit(ID, ";"))
  key <- unlist(strsplit(key, ";"))

  url <- paste("http://api.eia.gov/series?series_id=", ID, "&api_key=", key, 
               "&out=xml", sep = "")

  doc <- xmlParse(file = url, isURL = TRUE)

  df <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//series/row"))

  return(df)

}

val <- getWDEIA(ID = "PET.W_EPC0_FPF_R48_MBBLD.4", key = "E7FDCCBA39FBA0268555B7E81D73CD47")
```

If you look at the data frame returned, it would seem this is definitely not the data you are expecting:

```
glimpse(val)

## Observations: 1
## Variables:
## $ series_id   (fctr) PET.W_EPC0_FPF_R48_MBBLD.4
## $ name        (fctr) Lower 48 States Field Production of Crude Oil, 4 Week Avg
## $ units       (fctr) Thousand Barrels per Day
## $ f           (fctr) 4
## $ unitsshort  (fctr) Mbbl/d
## $ description (fctr) Lower 48 States Field Production of Crude Oil
## $ copyright   (fctr) None
## $ source      (fctr) EIA, U.S. Energy Information Administration
## $ start       (fctr) 
## $ end         (fctr) 
## $ updated     (fctr) 2015-08-05T13:14:06-0400
## $ data        (fctr)
```

Perhaps try another ID?